# Can I raise from wave.open() without it trying to close the file?

Tags: python, wave

I have some code that generates audio, and sometimes raises due to different reasons. I want to write the audio generated straight into a wav file. However, due to being inside the `wave`s context via `with`, `wave` tried to close the file. Now that is fine if it's later in the process, but if it's at the very beginning, `wave` doesn't have any params set, and dies.

Here's a MWE:

```py
from io import BytesIO
import wave

audio_out = BytesIO() 
with wave.open(audio_out, "w") as file_out:
    raise Exception('aaa!') 

Error: # channels not specified
```

The best I could come up with was to include `file_out.setparams((1, 1, 1, 1, 'NONE', ''))` at the very top, before anything gets a change to raise, and then overwrite those with the real params once I have them. It feels a bit dirty, though. Is there a better solution? Thanks!

### IDEA: Removing the context manager

I tried removing the context manager:

```py
file_out = wave.open(audio_out, "w")
raise Exception('aaa!')
```

but `wave` closes the file unconditionally still. The docs actually mention this: `Wave_write.close(): Make sure nframes is correct, and close the file if it was opened by wave. This method is called upon object collection. [...]` So what happens in this case is that I get a printout saying `Exception ignored in: <bound method Wave_write.__del__ of <wave.Wave_write object at 0x7ff549064eb8>> [...] wave.Error: # channels not specified`, which is still not satisfactory.

Comment: If you don't want 100% automatic, unconditional closing of the file, using a context manager will cause problems. I might change the `with` to a `try...finally`, then do a check in the `finally` and close it manually.

Comment: @Carcigenicate That's a good point, I tried that, but `wave` still tried to close the file, from the doc: `Wave_write.close(): Make sure nframes is correct, and close the file if it was opened by wave. This method is called upon object collection.` In other words, whether I use it as a context manager or not, the file seems to be closed unconditionally. I'll update the question!